# Mandar Array a través de Volley a Mysql desde SQLite

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite, android-volley, jsonarray

Actualmente estoy enviando datos de un formulario a través de la librería Volley a Mysql, el problema que me acontece es que necesito enviar los datos en Arrays directamente desde mi BD SQLite a Mysql y no desde el mismo formulario:

Tablas SQLite

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE formulario(\n" +
                "  id_formulario INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,\n" +
                "  id_oportunidad_fk int(11),\n" +
                "  fechaCreacion date,\n" +
                "  HoraTermino time,\n" +
                "  num_propiedad varchar(11),\n" +
                "  norma_aplicada varchar(50),\n" +
                "  artefactos_instalados varchar(200),\n" +
                "  FOREIGN KEY(id_oportunidad_fk) REFERENCES oportunidades(id_oportunidad));");

db.execSQL("create table oportunidades(\n" +
                "id_oportunidad INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,\n" +
                "fecha_oportunidad date NOT NULL,\n" +
                "fecha_creacion datetime NOT NULL,\n" +
                "hora time NOT NULL,\n" +
                "observacion varchar(1000) NOT NULL,\n" +
                "oportunidad int(11) NOT NULL;");
```

Intenté esta Lectura de datos SQLite pero es lo primero que no resulta

```
public Cabecera verCabecera(int id){

        DbHelper dbHelper = new DbHelper(context, "rs0401-2", null, 1);
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        Cabecera formulario = null;
        Cursor cursorCabecera = null;

        cursorCabecera = db.rawQuery("select * FROM formulario WHERE id_formulario = " + id + " LIMIT 1", null);

        if (cursorCabecera.moveToFirst()){
                formulario = new Cabecera();
                 Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    parameters.put("fecha", cursorCabecera.getString(0));
                    parameters.put("rancho", cursorCabecera.getString(1));
                    parameters.put("sector", cursorCabecera.getString(2));
                    parameters.put("trabajador", cursorCabecera.getString(3));
                    parameters.put("hora", cursorCabecera.getString(4));
                    ProcessRequest(parameters);
              
        }
        cursorCabecera.close();

        return formulario;

    }
```

No tengo problema con la API, pero si como generar el código de volley para que lea Array directamente desde SQLite.

Comment: ¿Cuál es tu problema en concreto? Debes mandar un `Map` al servidor y luego desglosarlo allí para insertarlo en MySQL o lo que sea. ¿El problema en sí cual es y qué errores tienes?

Comment: Mi problema es que no encuentro la forma de enviar todos los datos de la tabla MySQL

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Necesito mandar todos los datos de mis tablas sqlite a Mysql a través de la librería Volley